# Get characters before the numbers in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server which contains a characters and a random numbers or a dash and random character string. I want to split the character part. Does anyone have any suggestion?

```
create table stage.test(
    geo_area varchar(50) null
)
    
insert into stage.test values ('mobile-pensacola (ft walt) (686)')
insert into stage.test values ('rj-globo rio (76008)' )
insert into stage.test values ('ce2-tv (6666)' )
insert into stage.test values ('mumbai metropolitan region (356002)')
```

Tried this query which is not working as expected

```
 select left(geo_area, len(left(geo_area, 50) ) - 6)  as geo_area
 from stage.test
```

Expected output

```
    mobile-pensacola (ft walt)
    rj-globo rio
    ce2-tv
    mumbai metropolitan region
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It's not particularly clear from your description and you could format your sample data better - it looks like you are just removing the last set of parenthesis containing digits, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `patindex()` to find the first occurence of the sections to remove:

```
with sampledata as (
    select * from (values
        ('mobile-pensacola (ft walt) (686)'),
        ('rj-globo rio (76008)'),
        ('vz-jp '),
        ('mumbai metropolitan region (356002)')
    )x(col)
)
select Left(col, IsNull(NullIf(PatIndex('%([0-9]%', col)-1,-1),Len(col))) NewCol
from sampledata;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, if i have the blank or null values in the field , it is throwing the error. Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: This is different question .
How to get just the number out of the column, 
for example" the output should be 
686
76008
6666
356002
blank or null

Comment: @user15132810 I've amended the query above to handle null values for the data so `left` will work. By all means ask a new question!

Comment: Sure thanks and will ask different question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic solution based on tokenization.

It will remove islands of digits surrounded by any delimiter, parenthesis or otherwise,  regardless of their location. I added one extra row to demonstrate it.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl table (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, geo_area varchar(50) NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl (geo_area) VALUES
('mobile-pensacola (ft walt) (686)'),
('rj-globo rio (76008)'),
('ce2-tv (6666)'),
('mumbai metropolitan region (356002)'),
('mumbai (356002) metropolitan region');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.*
    , c.query('
       for $x in /root/r/text()
       return if (xs:int(substring($x,2,string-length($x) - 2)) instance of xs:int) then ()
            else data($x)
       ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(geo_area, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| ID |              geo_area               |           Result           |
+----+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | mobile-pensacola (ft walt) (686)    | mobile-pensacola (ft walt) |
|  2 | rj-globo rio (76008)                | rj-globo rio               |
|  3 | ce2-tv (6666)                       | ce2-tv                     |
|  4 | mumbai metropolitan region (356002) | mumbai metropolitan region |
|  5 | mumbai (356002) metropolitan region | mumbai metropolitan region |
+----+-------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```